# Why Can't SQL Server Management Studio Access The "My Documents" Folder in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, file-management, sql-server

I have a database backup located in my Windows 7 Documents folder (`C:\Users\Aaron\Documents...`), and I'm  trying to restore it using SQL Server Management Studio.  However, the program is unable to access anything within the Users\Aaron directory using its non-standard file selection dialog, even when run as an Administrator.

I'm brand new to Windows 7, is there some sort of security setting that I need to trigger to give programs access to these files?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found more information [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180107082911/http://bidn.com/Blogs/unable-to-browse-to-database-or-backup-file-location-from-ssms):

"To give your SQL Server account access to this folder, we first have to verify the account used to login to SQL Server. Open SQL Server Configuration Manager and navigate to SQL Server Services. Right-click SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) and select properties. On the Log On tab, you should see where the account to login as is specified."

Once you know the account being used by SQL Server, give that account the needed permissions on your directory.

Comment: Another method for finding the account name is opening Services and scroll down to SQL Server and note the value in the `Log On As` column

Answer (score 8):

Try giving the "Network Service" permissions on the folder. Worked for me.

Comment: Could you explain how you discovered that those permissions were needed?

Comment: This page on [sqlservercentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic461842-146-1.aspx#bm461877). However I didn't seem to have the security group they were talking about so I just added the network service account itself.  As I added it to each sub directory SSMS could drill one level further into my user directory. (p.s. not sure what the security implications of doing this are..)

Comment: This worked for me (Win Server 2008 & SQL Server 2008); but I also fear of the security implications of this.  There were five different SQL Server groups; and none of them none of them allowed Management Studio to access the directory.  The [Microsoft Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283235.aspx)  suggest that you don't change the "run as" account away from Network Service.